# Перебор массива и проверка наличия элементов char в string через Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Подскажите, пожалуйста, c таким вопросом. Даны два массива:

```
static String[] arr = {"Hello", "World", "Bobby", "Sam"};
static char[] chars = {'h', 'o'};
```

Каким образом можно только лишь с помощью Stream найти совпадения символов из массива char со строкой из массива String и вывести в консоль?

Я сделал такую реализацию, но подозреваю есть более правильное решение:

```
for (Character c : chars) {
    Arrays.stream(arr).filter(a -> a.contains(c.toString())).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: Должньі совпасть все символьі или как у вас? ))

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець должны вывестись все строки в которых есть любой из элементов массива char

Comment: Если любой то anyMatch

Comment: @AzizUmarov не подскажешь, почему chars() возвращает intStream? Почему так решили сделать разрабы?

Comment: Думаю да. И причина посмотрите на то у каких типов есть боксинг и анбоксинг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = {"Hello", "World", "Bobby", "Sam"};
    char[] chars = {'H', 'o'};

    Arrays.stream(arr)
        .filter(
            a ->
                new String(chars)
                    .chars()
                    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
                    .anyMatch(c -> a.contains(c.toString())))
        .forEach(System.out::println); // Hello World Bobby
  }
```